# minikube connection reset when trying to open service url

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

#### What Happened?

I have a minikube service cluster, but when I try

```
$ minikube service <service_name>
```

I get a connection reset.

---

```
$ kubectl get svc
```

returns

```
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
akhq              ClusterIP   10.109.242.181   <none>        8085/TCP    20h
connect           ClusterIP   10.96.106.62     <none>        8082/TCP    20h
kafka             ClusterIP   10.108.144.144   <none>        29092/TCP   20h
kubernetes        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP     21h
schema-registry   ClusterIP   10.106.216.158   <none>        8083/TCP    20h
zookeeper         ClusterIP   10.107.73.115    <none>        2181/TCP    20h
```

and

```
$ minikube service --all
```

returns

```
|-----------|------|-------------|--------------|
| NAMESPACE | NAME | TARGET PORT |     URL      |
|-----------|------|-------------|--------------|
| default   | akhq |             | No node port |
|-----------|------|-------------|--------------|
  service default/akhq has no node port
|-----------|---------|-------------|--------------|
| NAMESPACE |  NAME   | TARGET PORT |     URL      |
|-----------|---------|-------------|--------------|
| default   | connect |             | No node port |
|-----------|---------|-------------|--------------|
  service default/connect has no node port
|-----------|-------|-------------|--------------|
| NAMESPACE | NAME  | TARGET PORT |     URL      |
|-----------|-------|-------------|--------------|
| default   | kafka |             | No node port |
|-----------|-------|-------------|--------------|
  service default/kafka has no node port
|-----------|------------|-------------|--------------|
| NAMESPACE |    NAME    | TARGET PORT |     URL      |
|-----------|------------|-------------|--------------|
| default   | kubernetes |             | No node port |
|-----------|------------|-------------|--------------|
  service default/kubernetes has no node port
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|--------------|
| NAMESPACE |      NAME       | TARGET PORT |     URL      |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|--------------|
| default   | schema-registry |             | No node port |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|--------------|
  service default/schema-registry has no node port
|-----------|-----------|-------------|--------------|
| NAMESPACE |   NAME    | TARGET PORT |     URL      |
|-----------|-----------|-------------|--------------|
| default   | zookeeper |             | No node port |
|-----------|-----------|-------------|--------------|
  service default/zookeeper has no node port
  Starting tunnel for service akhq.
  Starting tunnel for service connect.
  Starting tunnel for service kafka.
  Starting tunnel for service kubernetes.
  Starting tunnel for service schema-registry.
  Starting tunnel for service zookeeper.
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |      NAME       | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------------|
| default   | akhq            |             | http://127.0.0.1:60491 |
| default   | connect         |             | http://127.0.0.1:60497 |
| default   | kafka           |             | http://127.0.0.1:60503 |
| default   | kubernetes      |             | http://127.0.0.1:60509 |
| default   | schema-registry |             | http://127.0.0.1:60515 |
| default   | zookeeper       |             | http://127.0.0.1:60521 |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------------|
  Opening service default/akhq in default browser...
  Opening service default/connect in default browser...
  Opening service default/kafka in default browser...
  Opening service default/kubernetes in default browser...
  Opening service default/schema-registry in default browser...
  Opening service default/zookeeper in default browser...
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

and then I get connection resets for all services except kubernetes, which tells me:

**Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.**

---

```
kubectl describe service akhq
```

returns

```
Name:              akhq
Namespace:         default
Labels:            io.kompose.service=akhq
Annotations:       kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f ../compose.yml
                   kompose.version: 1.26.1 (HEAD)
Selector:          io.kompose.service=akhq
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.109.242.181
IPs:               10.109.242.181
Port:              8085  8085/TCP
TargetPort:        8085/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.3:8085
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

#### Attach the log file

- 

#### Operating System

macOS (Default)

#### Driver

Docker